# Is it safe using xcrud on public facing pages?

Tags: php, crud

I'd like to show rows to the public. Let members only edit their row, field email, password, etc. Do the options restricting rows and permissions provide thorough security?

Comment: What options are you talking about?

Comment: These http://xcrud.com/demos/index.php?page=all_disabled&theme=default

And the initial WHERE ID = x